# Continuity of a function when domain and range are not real numbers

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}, f(x)=x$ and choose $\epsilon=\delta$ then

$\left| f(x)-f({ x }_{ 0 }) \right|<\epsilon$ and $\left| x- x _ 0\right|<\delta$ for $x_0,\epsilon,\delta\in D(f)$: so limit exists and the function is continuous(in its domain). Is it correct or I have done some blunder as I usually do.

My main question is: Can a function be continuous(in its domain) when domain and range are not real numbers. If not,why not? And if it is, then what type of continuity is this?

Comment: There's some problem with the latex,please fix it

Comment: A function can be continuous on its domain, not in its range.

Comment: Depends entirely on what $|\cdot|$ means in $Q$.  If $\forall x \in Q, \forall y \in Q \setminus \{x\}, |x-y| = \infty$, you will have some trouble...

Comment: I see no example of a definition of $|\cdot|$ on $Q$.

Comment: @EricTowers Why not just the restriction of $|.|$ to  $\mathbb{Q}$ ? Using the topological definition of continuity, you can consider a continuous function from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. I think that consider such a continuous function $f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ for the induced topology is equivalent to your formulation. You can even do it for $\mathbb{N}$, where actually any function (sequence) is continuous (for $\epsilon < 1$).

Comment: @YannHamdaoui:  Because I don't see $\mathbb{Q}$.  What I see in the title is that $Q$ does not contain real numbers, so it cannot be $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I understood it as "when the domain is not the whole set of rational numbers", and $Q$ as $\mathbb{Q}$, but i may be mistaken.

Comment: @YannHamdaoui:  I see that the problem statement has been updated to match your interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

The $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity is good for *any* function $f\colon S\to T$, with $S$ and $T$ being subsets of $\mathbb R$ of any kind whatever. Indeed, it’s good for any pair $(S,T)$ of metric spaces, but I guess you’re not yet at a stage where this should be important.

Answer (score 1):

## The Definition

Let $f$ be a function from some subset of $\mathbb{R}$, call it $D$ for *domain*, to another subset of $\mathbb{R}$, call it $C$ for *codomain*. That is,$$f:D\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to C\subseteq\mathbb{R}$$
Let $a$ be an arbitrary element of the domain. That is, $$a\in D$$
$f$ is continuous at $a$ if for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for each $x\in D$, if $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. Moreover, $f$ is **continuous** if for each $a\in D$, $f$ is continuous at $a$.

## An example

Define $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ by $$f(x)=x$$ for every $x\in \mathbb{Q}$.

$f$ is continuous.

Proof. To prove $f$ is continuous, we will show that for each $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ and for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for each $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, if $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-a|<\epsilon$.

Let $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ be arbitrary. Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. We will show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that for each $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, if $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

Define $\delta\overset{\text{def}}{=}\epsilon$. We will show that for each $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, if $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

Let $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ be arbitrary. We will show that if $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

Assume $|x-a|<\delta$. We will show that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

$$|f(x)-f(a)|=|x-a|<\delta=\epsilon$$
We have shown that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

As a result, $f$ is continuous.$\square$

The definition alone should answer your question. The proof above is much too pedantic, but I believe that it will be instructive for understanding what **continuity** is, and how to utilize the definition to prove functions are indeed **continuous** such as $f$.